# macos: how can I remove asking a pssword for this command /usr/bin/security dump-keychain -d

Tags: macos, security, terminal, keychain

I'm running in terminal the following code

`/usr/bin/security dump-keychain -d`

and its asking me for a password from my chain.
is it possible to remove it somehow?